# Cambiar color de fondo en una etiqueta si sobrepasa un valor X

Tags: java

Estimados tengo un aplicacion que convierte metros x segundo a kilometros x hora, quiero saber como puedo cambiar el color de fondo de la etiqueta si sobrepasa X valor:

Ejemplo se la velocidad son 50 km/hora se pinte Rojo el fondo de la etiqueta.

Adjunto metodo y el evento

```
public class Operacion {

  public double Resultado;


  public void calcular(double n1){

  Resultado = n1 * 3.6;
}
```

> Evento

```
}


private void campoN1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        double num1 = Double.parseDouble(campoN1.getText());

        operar.calcular(num1);

        labelResult.setText(String.valueOf(operar.Resultado));
    }
```

Comment: Con la función `setBackground`. Como sabes el valor que tiene, si supera tu límite, ejecutas la función pasándole un color.

Comment: Hola, estoy comenzando en programación, si pudieras darme un poco más de ayuda gracias

Comment: En el primer link de una búsqueda en google tienes ejemplos a montones.